# How can I add accounts on Kali Linux?

Tags: kali-linux

[image]

I can't add accounts manually. It shows that it has to be unlocked. What to do?

I used the command

```
useradd -m username -p password
```

, but it worked and created folders in home directory, but I still can't log in with the created users. It says, the password is wrong. My Kali version is rolling 3.25.92.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using Kali Linux.

Maybe you could consider reboot and press `Ctrl+Alt+F5` into multi-user text mode. Login with `root` or your username, reset your account, then reboot again.

Comment: i actually dont got what you said